Replace Inf, Inf in a Raster Stack
I can't seem to figure out how to replace all the Inf and -Inf in a raster stack
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.29

nrows <- 10
ncols <- 10
set.seed(123) 
r1 <- rast(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols, xmin = 0, xmax = 10, vals = sample(0:8, nrows * ncols, replace = TRUE))
r1 <- c(rep(list(r1), 10))  
values(r1[[4]]) <- NaN  
values(r1[[7]]) <- NaN 
r1 <- rast(r1)
r2 <- classify(r1, cbind(-Inf, 0, NA))

What am I doing wrong?

Do you want to change all NaN/-Inf to NA? Or something else?

And quite likely you'll want to update your version of terra for work going forward. Mine is 1.7.81 and I feel behind as it is under constant development/improvement.

@LTyrone yes, and I have actually figured out I had a bigger problem, I asked a separate question

You can use terra::subst.
Example data
library(terra)
#terra 1.8.0
x <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10, nlyr=2, vals=1:200)
x[1] <- -Inf
x[2] <- Inf

Solution
y <- subst(x, c(-Inf, Inf), NA)
y[1:3]
#  lyr.1 lyr.2
#1    NA    NA
#2    NA    NA
#3     3   103

You can also use classify (that is a bit less efficient)
m <- cbind(c(-Inf, Inf), NA)
z <- classify(x, m)
z[1:3]
#  lyr.1 lyr.2
#1    NA    NA
#2    NA    NA
#3     3   103

Or, the least efficient way, use ifel:
ifel(is.finite(x), x, NA)
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 2  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (CRS84) (OGC:CRS84) 
#source(s)   : memory
#names       : lyr.1, lyr.2 
#min values  :     3,   103 
#max values  :   100,   200 


I have actually realised I had another problem, this r2 <- weighted.mean(r1, r2, na.rm=TRUE) return the error
Error: [weighted.mean] raster has no values. I will ask another question with an example
